# Compare Query_String and existing file

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to check that file specified in query_string exists.
I have already this rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^src=([^&]+)(.*)$
RewriteCond %1 -f
RewriteRule ^media/resizer/?(?:index\.php)?$ http://cdn.mysite.com/media/resizer/ [NC,R,L,QSA]
```

In %1 I have exact path to file name which I try to check for existence in second line. But it just checking for pattern '-f' 
RewriteLog:

```
RewriteCond: input='src=/forumsdata/images/avatars/james.jpg&w=120&h=120&zc=1' pattern='^src=([^&]+)(.*)$' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/forumsdata/images/avatars/james.jpg' pattern='-f' => not-matched
```

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f is media/resizer/index.php and that way doesn't work.

Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same "problem" with %{REQUEST_FILENAME}. %{REQUEST_FILENAME} according to the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) references:

> The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the
>   request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time
>   REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in
>   virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI. Depending on the
>   value of AcceptPathInfo, the server may have only used some leading
>   components of the REQUEST_URI to map the request to a file.

So if this is a virtual host setup you may need to reference the full path by using %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} like so:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```